# share video on Facebook from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

How do I share video link (video(.mov format) is on server and want to share link of it through my iPhone app)??
I am able to to send the link of the video and send an image along with it.
But when I click on the link the video is playing in the other page.
All I want is that the video is played on the same page and my image should act as thumbnail image.

Comment: Instead of sending the link to the video, upload the bytes of the video.  That way Facebook will convert it and host the video for you, and that video will be sharable in a user's stream.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with facebook dialog using the following parameters:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           title, @"name",
                                           caption, @"caption",
                                           description, @"description",
                                           itemLink, @"link",
                                           source, @"source",
                                           thumbnailURL, @"picture",
                                           @"video", @"type",
                                           nil];
```

The source is the embedded video source+player and the link is where the user will go if they click on your title (e.g. the video on your webpage).